# WebApi endpoint always gives "404 not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement WebApi endpoints in a brand new web app but no matter what I try I always get "404 not found" when trying to do a GET from said endpoint.

[image: localhost/api/dataservice/vehicles not found]

I'm starting simple and just trying to pull a list of vehicles from the database.

The directory structure of my application looks like so:

[image: directory structure]

The relevant bits of code look like so:

**dataService.js**

```
(function () {

var injectParams = ['vehiclesService'];

var dataService = function (vehiclesService) {
    return vehiclesService;
};

dataService.$inject = injectParams;

angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics').factory('dataService', dataService);
}());
```

**vehiclesService.js**

```
(function () {

var injectParams = ['$http', '$q'];

var vehiclesFactory = function ($http, $q) {
    var serviceBase = '/api/dataservice/',
        factory = {};

    factory.getVehicles = function () {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'vehicles').then(function (response) {
            var vehicles = response.data;
            return {
                totalRecords: parseInt(response.headers('X-InlineCount')),
                results: vehicles
            };
        });
    };

    return factory;
};

vehiclesFactory.$inject = injectParams;

angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics').factory('vehiclesService', vehiclesFactory);
}());
```

**DataServiceController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TeleAiDiagnostics
{
    public class DataServiceController : ApiController
    {
        TeleAiRepository _TeleAiRepository;

        public DataServiceController()
        {
            _TeleAiRepository = new TeleAiRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Vehicles()
        {
            List<TeleAiVehicle> vehicles = _TeleAiRepository.GetVehicles();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-inlineCount", vehicles.Count.ToString());
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vehicles);
        }
    }
}
```

**vehiclesController.js**

```
(function () {
    var injectParams = ['$location', 'dataService'];

    var VehiclesController = function ($location, dataService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.vehicles = [];

        function init() {
            dataService.getVehicles()
                .then(function (data) {
                    vm.vehicles = data.results;
                }, function (error) {
                    var thisError = error.data.message;
                });
        };

        init();
    };

    VehiclesController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('teleAiDiagnostics').controller('VehiclesController', VehiclesController);
}());
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace TeleAiDiagnostics
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            // Remove default XML handler
            var matches = config.Formatters
                                .Where(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes
                                             .Where(m => m.MediaType.ToString() == "application/xml" ||
                                                         m.MediaType.ToString() == "text/xml")
                                             .Count() > 0)
                                .ToList();

            foreach (var match in matches)
                config.Formatters.Remove(match);
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TeleAiDiagnostics
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
namespace TeleAiDiagnostics
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
    }
}
```

I've tried the instructions from about every tutorial I could find online and I'm still not having any luck.

Whatever help can be provided is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `RoutePrefix` attribute on the API Controller?

Comment: I have tried adding `[RoutePrefix("dataservice")]` to **DataServiceController.cs** but it did not help. I also tried adding `[RoutePrefix("dataservice/vehicles")]` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an answer!

Dan Dumitru and jps were both correct. After trying IIS Express I realized my error.

The endpoint is indeed `http://localhost/TeleAiDiagnostics/api/dataservice/vehicles` and not simply `http://localhost/api/dataservice/vehicles`.

Not sure why it took this long for me to realize this. Regardless, I want to thank everyone for their help.

Comment: thanks, but after reconsidering on my way back home I think my idea with the port is wrong because with a wrong port number you would get a different error (50x ?)  because the client won't reach any service. Anyway, good to hear it's solved :).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing the port number. When you start your WebApi project in Visual Studio, the WebApi will probably be hosted by in IISExpress. On the properties page you'll find the address and port in the WEB tab:

[image]

You have to add the port number to the address in your Angular code

eg.: http://localhost:46452/api/dataservice/vehicles

Comment: I thought of that already. I'm using Local IIS as my web server so no port numbers.

http://imgur.com/a/Ldifu

Comment: @Ian - Maybe then the URL should be  `http://localhost/TeleAiDiagnostics/api/dataservice`?

Comment: @Ian No port numbers? Is it possible? Better check that again, I think your service will listen on some kind of port number. Or reconfigure to use IIS Express as shown above and try with the portnumber.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of your default Web API route. I *think* it should be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

(without the `{action}` part)

Comment: I've changed it to look like so:

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Still no dice.

I've also tired modifying **vehiclesService.js** to eliminate the `dataservice` part but it's still not working.

Comment: @Ian - If you just go from your browser to `http://localhost/api/dataservice`, do you still get a 404?

Comment: I do still get a 404. Same thing for `http://localhost/api/dataservice/vehicles` and `http://localhost/api/vehicles`.

Comment: @Ian - It seems there is something wrong with your Web API routing. You could create a new simple Web API project, see if the default routes work, and build up from there.

Comment: I think this is the way it'll have to go. I'll work this out and check back in when I've found a solution.